# Get all related records using associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm unable to understand how to get all related records using associations instead of associated ids like `user_id` and `comment_id`.
Lets suppose I have three models `User, Post, Comment, Image` and associations are

```
User
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

Post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :images

Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

Image
  belongs_to :post
```

Now I have an `user_id` of user and finding user as:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
@comments = @user.comments
```

now I would like to fetch these comments with each of them a related record of their post. I want post hash instead of `post_id` corresponding to every comment.
I want to do this in a single query.
If you have any idea, please suggest me.

Comment: Try `@user.comments.first.post`, it will return a `Post` instance. Beware of a [“N+1 query`](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/) problem within this approach to be resolved, but this is out of scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration @mudasobwa . But My question is I want comments collection with already have post record corresponding to each comment instead of post_id. I don't want to make a loop to get post of each of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `includes(:association)`:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
@comments = @user.comments.includes(:post)
```

NOTE: This would make another (second) query.

Alternatively, include it in your initial query:

```
@user = User.where(id: params[:id]).includes(comments: :post)
```

Comment: Sorry @Uzbekjon, this will cause the error of Association named 'posts' was not found on Comments.

Comment: That's a typo. Just change it to `post` since it is a `belongs_to` association.

Comment: okay @Uzbekjon. This will not replace the post_id from the comments collection. This will return post_id again instead of complete post hash

Comment: It will not replace `post_id`, but it will also contain an attribute named `post`. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations